# How should I use and add other color on Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, colors

I've made a program that clicks on the color of the image and displays the color in text, but for now I can only use a few basic colors, basic colors like black, red or yellow, etc. If I want to join other colors such as pink or light blue, how can I do, if I may, you can also set a range of colors it? set, for example # FF0000 ~ # FF6347 is red (color code used here 16bit)

My problem in Color.XXX this part can not be customized

```
            int touchedRGB = orgbmp.getPixel(x, y);

            if(touchedRGB == Color.BLACK)
                colorshow.setText("Is Black");
            if(touchedRGB == Color.RED)
                colorshow.setText("Is RED");
            if(touchedRGB == Color.GREEN)
                colorshow.setText("Is GREEN");
            if(touchedRGB == Color.BLUE)
                colorshow.setText("Is Blue");
            if(touchedRGB == Color.GRAY)
                colorshow.setText("Is Gary");
            if(touchedRGB == Color.YELLOW)
                colorshow.setText("Is Yellow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener

```
public class MainActivity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener
{
   private Paint mPaint;  

    mPaint = new Paint();
   // on button click
    new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();

}
```

ColorPicker Dialog

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

public interface OnColorChangedListener {
void colorChanged(int color);
}

 private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
 private int mInitialColor;

private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
private Paint mPaint;
private Paint mCenterPaint;
private final int[] mColors;
private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
    super(c);
    mListener = l;
    mColors = new int[] {
        0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
        0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
    };
    Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setShader(s);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32);

    mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
    mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
}

private boolean mTrackingCenter;
private boolean mHighlightCenter;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth()*0.5f;

    canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

    canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

    if (mTrackingCenter) {
        int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
        mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        if (mHighlightCenter) {
            mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
        } else {
            mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(0, 0,
                          CENTER_RADIUS + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(),
                          mCenterPaint);

        mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
}

private static final int CENTER_X = 100;
private static final int CENTER_Y = 100;
private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;

private int floatToByte(float x) {
    int n = java.lang.Math.round(x);
    return n;
}
private int pinToByte(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        n = 0;
    } else if (n > 255) {
        n = 255;
    }
    return n;
}

private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
    return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
}

private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
    if (unit <= 0) {
        return colors[0];
    }
    if (unit >= 1) {
        return colors[colors.length - 1];
    }

    float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
    int i = (int)p;
    p -= i;

    // now p is just the fractional part [0...1) and i is the index
    int c0 = colors[i];
    int c1 = colors[i+1];
    int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
    int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
    int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
    int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

    return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
}

private int rotateColor(int color, float rad) {
    float deg = rad * 180 / 3.1415927f;
    int r = Color.red(color);
    int g = Color.green(color);
    int b = Color.blue(color);

    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    ColorMatrix tmp = new ColorMatrix();

    cm.setRGB2YUV();
    tmp.setRotate(0, deg);
    cm.postConcat(tmp);
    tmp.setYUV2RGB();
    cm.postConcat(tmp);

    final float[] a = cm.getArray();

    int ir = floatToByte(a[0] * r +  a[1] * g +  a[2] * b);
    int ig = floatToByte(a[5] * r +  a[6] * g +  a[7] * b);
    int ib = floatToByte(a[10] * r + a[11] * g + a[12] * b);

    return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), pinToByte(ir),
                      pinToByte(ig), pinToByte(ib));
}

private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
    float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
    boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
            if (inCenter) {
                mHighlightCenter = true;
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mTrackingCenter) {
                if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                    mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                    invalidate();
                }
            } else {
                float angle = (float)java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
                float unit = angle/(2*PI);
                if (unit < 0) {
                    unit += 1;
                }
                mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (mTrackingCenter) {
                if (inCenter) {
                    mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());
                }
                mTrackingCenter = false;    // so we draw w/o halo
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}

public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                     OnColorChangedListener listener,
                     int initialColor) {
super(context);

mListener = listener;
mInitialColor = initialColor;
}

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mListener.colorChanged(color);
        dismiss();
    }
};

setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor));
setTitle("Pick a Color");
}
```

You have to choose the color and click the center circle to pick the color. Set the color to your paint object and use the same to draw.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Masoud Mokhtari, this method as you can customize the color you want, but I need to define multiple colors at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Creating a resource file matching color name and color codes will solve the problem instead of using `Color` module like [here](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/list-of-color-names-and-color-code-for-android/)

`getResources().getStringArray` and `getResources().obtainTypedArray` can be used to loop over and match the names & color codes.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want, thank you I am batman, by the way there any examples using getResources (). GetStringArray and getResources (). ObtainTypedArray can reference?

Comment: I just want to call out the color in the color.xml. It is not used here to change the color and background color of the Textview. Like the constant color in sRGB such as Color.black, it can be used in the program